# Is this string of words an independent clause "Historically, the lands that are now parts of New York and Delaware."

Tags: clauses, compound-subjects, sentence

Is the below sentence a compound sentence?

Historically, the Lenape inhabited lands that are now parts of New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New York, and they settled along the rivers and bays.

I don't think "The Lenape..." is an independent clause. Is it?

Comment: Yes: **compound** sentences are linked by coordination, usually with one of the coordinators "and", "or" or "but". Complex sentences, by contrast, are linked by subordination using such words as "that", "whether" or "if".

Comment: Note that the relative clause _that are now parts of New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New York_ is a subordinate clause in noun phrase structure, not in clause structure, so it has no relevance to the status of the sentence as a compound one. The two independent clauses are _historically, the Lenape inhabited lands that are now parts of New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New York_  **+** _they settled along the rivers and bays_.

Comment: No. It's a sentence adverb and a noun phrase, that you have for some reason concatenated.

Answer (score 2):

That is a compound sentence: **two separate sentences joined by an *and***.

Historically, the Lenape inhabited lands that are now parts of New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New York, ***and*** they settled along the rivers and bays.

1. Historically, the Lenape inhabited lands that are now parts of New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New York.
2. They settled along the rivers and bays.

[I have dyslexia where *two items* are concerned, so I wrote complex instead of compound but that is now corrected.]

Comment: Isn't a complex sentence supposed to also have a dependent clause in it?

Comment: No. These sentences are completely independent of one another and joined by an. The boy ran home and the girl walked to school.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was curious whether the first part of the sentence is an independent clause or not because of "lands that are".

Comment: **that are now part of a, b and c**  is a dependent clause. The clause starts with the word that. And cannot stand on its own as a sentence. :)

Comment: In your main answer is (1.) an independent clause?

Comment: No, this is the parse. independent clause:  Historically, the Lenape inhabited lands///dependent clause: that are now parts of New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New York. Anything AFTER the words *that or which* like that constitute a dependent clause.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I think the second independent clause starts with the word **and**, and can stand on its own as a sentence. :)

Comment: @LucianSava I don't disagree, except I prefer to say independent when there is dependent one in sight. In other words, a sentence like: He lives on this street. for me is SVP but I would not mention independent clause in that regard...

Answer (score 2):

> **[** *Historically, the Lenape inhabited lands that are now parts of New*
> *Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New York* **]**, and **[** *they settled along*
> *the rivers and bays* **]**.

This is a compound sentence consisting of two independent clauses. Compound sentences are linked by coordination, usually with one of the coordinators "and", "or" or "but".

Note that the relative clause *that are now parts of New Jersey, Pennsylvania*, *Delaware, and New York* is a subordinate clause in noun phrase structure, not in clause structure, so it has no relevance to the status of the sentence as a compound one.

I've bracketed the two independent clauses.